# Rails - Pass current_user into SQL query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm looking for a way to pass the Rails/Devise variable "current_user" into a SQL query.

I have an app with two models, Users and Tips. Users can friend other users and send tips to each other. I'm trying to display a user's friend list ordered by the number of tips that the user has sent to each friend, so that the friend to whom the user has sent the most tips shows up at the top of the friend list, and so on.

I've read that RoR isn't equipped to handle this kind of query easily, so I've been able to put together the following SQL query, which works fine:

```
def friend_list
 @friends = User.find_by_sql("SELECT users.*, 
 COUNT(tips.id) AS c FROM users, tips 
 WHERE tips.recipient_id = users.id 
 AND tips.user_id = 3
 GROUP BY users.id ORDER BY c DESC")
end
```

The only problem is, I have manually entered a user.id there ("3") when ideally that "3" would be replaced by "current_user" so that each time a user loads this list they get their friend list ranked by who they themselves have sent tips to, rather than everyone just seeing user 3's ranking.

In an ideal world this would look something like:

```
 AND tips.user_id = current_user
```

but that doesn't work. How can I pass a variable into this query so that it is different for each person viewing?

UPDATE:
User model (excerpt):

```
has_many :tips
has_many :received_tips, :class_name => "Tip", :foreign_key => "recipient_id"
```

Tip model (excerpt):

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => "User"
```

Comment: What do your models for tips and users look like?

Comment: I added the bits of each in which they reference each other. The user model also has a bunch of friendship logic but since that deals with a third model called Friendships that is not dealt with here I left it out. Let me know if you think that's also relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access current_user in models if using `devise`...though there are few good ways to do it

```
        ##method one---in your controller

        @users=User.find(current_user.id)   

        ##method two---in your controller

        @users=User.get_user_details(current_user.id)   

        ##in model
        def self.get_user_details(current_user_id)
          User.find(current_user_id)
        end

       ###you can also use in this way in controller

      @all_videos = Video.where("videos.user_id !=?",current_user.id)

.........so this can be your solution............

##in controller or pass current_user and user it in your model

def friend_list
 @friends = User.joins(:tips).select("users.* and count(tips.id) as c").where  ("tips.users_id= ?",current_user.id).group("users.id").order("c DESC")    
 ##or
 @friends = User.all(:joins => :tips, :select => "users.*, count(tips.id) as    tips_count", :group => "users.id",:order=>"tips_count DESC")

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
def friend_list
 @friends = User.find_by_sql("SELECT users.*, 
 COUNT(tips.id) AS c FROM users, tips 
 WHERE tips.recipient_id = users.id 
 AND tips.user_id = ?
 GROUP BY users.id ORDER BY c DESC", current_user.id)
end
```

Anyway it is not that hard to do this query using active_record.

Comment: Thanks, trying that now, but if you could tell me how to do it in ActiveRecord that would be amazing - I'm trying to learn ActiveRecord and this would be a great example.

Comment: Tried the above and got the following error: undefined method `map' for 3:Fixnum. Any idea what that means?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I want to add that you could also use string injection.

```
def friend_list

 #Declare the query string you want to pass
 @query = "SELECT users.*, 
     COUNT(tips.id) AS c FROM users, tips 
     WHERE tips.recipient_id = users.id 
     AND tips.user_id = #{current_user.id}
     GROUP BY users.id ORDER BY DESC"

 @friends = User.find_by_sql(@query)
end
```